# Filtrar data por intervalos de horas até ultima hora possivel dentro do mesmo dia

Tags: sql, oracle

**A regra**

Todos os registros que estiverem dentro de um intervalo de 1 hora, devem ser contados como 1 registros somente.

**Dados**

```
ID     DATA

1      06/07/2017 09:20:35
2      06/07/2017 10:20:35
3      06/07/2017 10:25:30
4      06/07/2017 10:40:35
5      06/07/2017 10:50:35
6      06/07/2017 11:25:30
7      06/07/2017 11:50:20
8      06/07/2017 15:25:30
9      06/07/2017 17:25:30
10     06/07/2017 17:30:30
11     06/07/2017 17:40:55
```

**Resultado esperado**

```
count       data

5           06/07/2017
```

Por que? Por que a partir da menor data, os registros que estiverem "dentro" de até uma hora após essa data, conta como 1 só. Mais ou menos isso:

```
count       range_data

1           09:20:35 - 10:20:35
1           10:20:36 - 11:20:36
1           11:20:37 - 12:20:37
0           12:20:38 - 13:20:38
0           13:20:39 - 14:20:39
0           14:20:40 - 15:20:40
1           15:20:41 - 16:20:41
1           17:20:42 - 18:20:41
```

Alguma sugestão para fazer isso? Sem ser com interatividade (for/while). Pq eu posso ter N datas no meio, eu não tenho um "padrão" de datas mínimas e máximas... a unica coisa que eu sei é que as datas estão dentro do mesmo dia.

Eu não quero ter que fazer N selects para contar entre hora e hora...

Comment: Acho que no minimo você vai ter que adotar o padrão de horas de 00:00 M:S a 59:59 Minutos:Segundos. no seu exemplo você tem  09:20:35 - 10:20:35, isso se torna muito variável uma vez que não tem inicio nem fim para começa/terminar.

Comment: "Não tem" e tem ao mesmo tempo...já que é tudo no mesmo dia, certo? O ponto é pegar sempre a menor data e a maior... e bolar uma logica de fazer tudo na mesma query rs

Comment: você que dizer que nesse caso a menor data é 09:20:35 e conta 1 hora após isso para o final, e depois busca a próxima hora e conta mais 1 hora  para o final e assim por diante.

Comment: Sim... minha menor data pode ser às 07:15:00, por exemplo...é sempre 1 hora a partir dela...até a maior data. entendeu?

Comment: Acho que você poderia usar algo assim. Os numeros não tem sentido e precisam ser ajustados para sua realidade.

select min( id ), case when ( data >= getdate() - 20 or data <= getdate() - 30 ) then 'ontem'
                       when ( data >= getdate() or data <= getdate() - 4 )  then 'hoje'
                       when ( data >= getdate() + 12 or data <= getdate() - 20 ) then 'amanha'  end as data from teste
group by data

Comment: @MarllonNasser, entendi , você precisa mostra o total e o intervalos de horas?

Comment: Preciso de um total por DIA. Em linhas curtas, para cada intervalo que eu tiver registro, eu incremento meu contador.

Comment: A BASE SERIA ALGO COMO SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS') CHEIA, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH24'),'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS') TRUNCADA FROM DUAL

CHEIA                                                                       TRUNCADA                                                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------
06/07/16 12:33:25                                                           06/07/16 12:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta dada no [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225738/filter-date-with-intervals-of-1-hour-between-two-random-dates-in-the-same-day/38225900#38225900):

```
SELECT 
    TRUNC(dt) AS data, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(dt - 20 / (24 * 60) - (35 + TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dt, 'HH24')) - 9) / (24 * 60 * 60), 'HH24')) AS qtd
FROM tabela
GROUP BY TRUNC(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja assim:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTE
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT  COUNT(*),  MIN( DATA ) FROM TESTE
GROUP BY ( DAY( DATA ) * 100000000 ) + (  MONTH( DATA ) * 1000000 ) +  YEAR(DATA  )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não é isso que era esperado, de acordo com a pergunta?

Comment: Não, amigo.... veja lá: o esperado é algo como: `5           06/07/2017`

Comment: E não foi o que retornou na primeira linha?

Comment: Sim, mas você usou um caso de dados diferente do meu. Baseado no seu, eu teria que ter um resultado de `1      2016-07-06`, porque os registros estão dentro de um intervalo de uma hora, então eu conto todos como um só.

Comment: Hmmm. Desculpa ai. Eu fechei por dia.  De fato fechando por hora em meu caso de dados teria de voltar 12 porque estão todos contidos na mesma hora, porém de dias diferentes.   Fechando por hora teria que ser algo assim: 

SELECT  COUNT(*),  MIN( DATA ) FROM TESTE
GROUP BY DATEPART( hour, data ) + ( DATEPART( minute, data ) * 60 )


Desde que o select se restrinja a um dia. Senão teria que colocar o dia no group by também.